# Brightness function key : very slow response

Tags: kernel, brightness, asus, intel

I'm running ubuntu 14.04 on my **Asus K55VD**.

brightness **low** function key is responding very late : aprox 30-45 seconds later the brightness is reduced.

but rest of the others functions(Brightness **Up** ,volume **+ -**)keys works fine. 
there is been only problem with brightness **low** key

Any solutions ?

more info :

my kernel version :

```
3.19.0-49-generic
```

P:S :

**cat /proc/cmdline**

```
BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-49-generic root=UUID=bf489b0f-7029-4916-b2cb-5794abbc315d ro quiet splash intel_pstate=enable vt.handoff=7
```

**lspci -k | grep -iA2 VGA**

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 1457
    Kernel driver in use: i915
--
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF119M [GeForce 610M] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 1457
03:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
```

**for interface in /sys/class/backlight/*; do echo -e "\n $interface"; cat $interface/{brightness,max_brightness,actual_brightness}; done**

```
/sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight
3771
4882
3771
```

**lsmod**

```
Module                  Size  Used by
nvram                  16384  0 
msr                    16384  0 
pci_stub               16384  1 
vboxpci                24576  0 
vboxnetadp             28672  0 
vboxnetflt             28672  0 
vboxdrv               417792  3 vboxnetadp,vboxnetflt,vboxpci
ctr                    16384  1 
ccm                    20480  1 
bnep                   20480  2 
rfcomm                 69632  4 
binfmt_misc            20480  1 
ath3k                  20480  0 
uvcvideo               90112  0 
videobuf2_vmalloc      16384  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_memops       16384  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
videobuf2_core         53248  1 uvcvideo
v4l2_common            16384  1 videobuf2_core
videodev              159744  3 uvcvideo,v4l2_common,videobuf2_core
btusb                  40960  0 
bluetooth             491520  12 bnep,ath3k,btusb,rfcomm
media                  24576  2 uvcvideo,videodev
ip6t_REJECT            16384  1 
nf_reject_ipv6         16384  1 ip6t_REJECT
nf_log_ipv6            16384  4 
xt_hl                  16384  6 
ip6t_rt                16384  3 
nf_conntrack_ipv6      20480  10 
nf_defrag_ipv6         36864  1 nf_conntrack_ipv6
ipt_REJECT             16384  1 
nf_reject_ipv4         16384  1 ipt_REJECT
nf_log_ipv4            16384  4 
nf_log_common          16384  2 nf_log_ipv4,nf_log_ipv6
xt_LOG                 16384  8 
xt_limit               16384  11 
xt_tcpudp              16384  18 
xt_addrtype            16384  4 
nf_conntrack_ipv4      16384  10 
nf_defrag_ipv4         16384  1 nf_conntrack_ipv4
xt_conntrack           16384  20 
ip6table_filter        16384  1 
ip6_tables             28672  1 ip6table_filter
nf_conntrack_netbios_ns    16384  0 
nf_conntrack_broadcast    16384  1 nf_conntrack_netbios_ns
nf_nat_ftp             16384  0 
nf_nat                 24576  1 nf_nat_ftp
nf_conntrack_ftp       20480  1 nf_nat_ftp
nf_conntrack          106496  8 nf_nat_ftp,nf_conntrack_netbios_ns,nf_nat,xt_conntrack,nf_conntrack_broadcast,nf_conntrack_ftp,nf_conntrack_ipv4,nf_conntrack_ipv6
iptable_filter         16384  1 
ip_tables              28672  1 iptable_filter
x_tables               36864  13 ip6table_filter,xt_hl,ip_tables,xt_tcpudp,xt_limit,xt_conntrack,xt_LOG,iptable_filter,ip6t_rt,ipt_REJECT,ip6_tables,xt_addrtype,ip6t_REJECT
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     53248  1 
snd_hda_codec_realtek    86016  1 
snd_hda_codec_generic    69632  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
intel_rapl             20480  0 
iosf_mbi               16384  1 intel_rapl
x86_pkg_temp_thermal    16384  0 
intel_powerclamp       20480  0 
coretemp               16384  0 
kvm_intel             151552  0 
asus_nb_wmi            24576  0 
asus_wmi               24576  1 asus_nb_wmi
sparse_keymap          16384  1 asus_wmi
snd_hda_intel          36864  4 snd_hda_codec_hdmi
kvm                   479232  1 kvm_intel
snd_hda_controller     32768  1 snd_hda_intel
snd_hda_codec         143360  5 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_controller
snd_hwdep              20480  1 snd_hda_codec
crct10dif_pclmul       16384  0 
crc32_pclmul           16384  0 
cryptd                 20480  0 
joydev                 20480  0 
arc4                   16384  2 
serio_raw              16384  0 
snd_pcm               106496  4 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_controller
ath9k                 147456  0 
ath9k_common           32768  1 ath9k
snd_seq_midi           16384  0 
ath9k_hw              458752  2 ath9k_common,ath9k
snd_seq_midi_event     16384  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_rawmidi            32768  1 snd_seq_midi
ath                    32768  3 ath9k_common,ath9k,ath9k_hw
mac80211              712704  1 ath9k
rtsx_pci_ms            20480  0 
snd_seq                65536  2 snd_seq_midi_event,snd_seq_midi
memstick               20480  1 rtsx_pci_ms
nouveau              1368064  0 
lpc_ich                24576  0 
i915                 1048576  4 
cfg80211              524288  4 ath,ath9k_common,ath9k,mac80211
snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi
snd_timer              32768  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
snd                    86016  17 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hwdep,snd_timer,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_pcm,snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_seq_device
mxm_wmi                16384  1 nouveau
mei_me                 20480  0 
ttm                    94208  1 nouveau
soundcore              16384  2 snd,snd_hda_codec
mei                    90112  1 mei_me
drm_kms_helper        126976  2 i915,nouveau
drm                   344064  8 ttm,i915,drm_kms_helper,nouveau
shpchp                 40960  0 
i2c_algo_bit           16384  2 i915,nouveau
wmi                    20480  3 mxm_wmi,nouveau,asus_wmi
video                  20480  3 i915,nouveau,asus_wmi
mac_hid                16384  0 
parport_pc             32768  0 
ppdev                  20480  0 
lp                     20480  0 
parport                45056  3 lp,ppdev,parport_pc
hid_generic            16384  0 
usbhid                 53248  0 
hid                   110592  2 hid_generic,usbhid
rtsx_pci_sdmmc         24576  0 
psmouse               118784  0 
ahci                   36864  3 
libahci                32768  1 ahci
r8169                  81920  0 
rtsx_pci               49152  2 rtsx_pci_ms,rtsx_pci_sdmmc
mii
```

**pastebinit /var/log/Xorg.0.log**

http://paste.ubuntu.com/15024859/

Comment: Try this - http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2208278 find out and specify right video device.

Comment: @ulcha please check updated question :)